# Assign a class to a this keyword

Tags: c#, this

I'm using these two classes in seperate files to open a window in game. It works, but is there a simpler way to do `GUI.Check = this` without assigning an instance to the other class. Ex. `MyClass = this`

(Sorry for incorrect naming of things)

```
public class MyClass
{
    public WindowClass GUI;

    public void OpenGUI()
    {
        if (!GUI.open)
        {
            GUI.Check = this;
            GUI.open = true;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class WindowClass
{
    public bool open = false;
    public MyClass Check;

    public void Display()
    {
        if (open)
        {
            // GUI stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on what you declare your variable as, and what `this` refers to when you're trying to assign it to a variable.

Comment: Create a constructor in the `WindowClass` class which takes a `MyClass` parameter and assigned it to the `check` member. Then, when you create that class from a `MyClass` method, pass `this`, then the explicit assignment is unnecessary.

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking. Are you asking for different syntax for `GUI.MyClass = this`? (Side note: you never "assign a class" in C# - maybe "assign instance of the class"... Also title of the post makes absolutely no sense as you can't assign anything to `this` at all)

Comment: I assume that your _WindowClass_ instance needs a reference to the _MyClass_ instance. If this is the case, then I think @JesseC.Slicer 's proposal is the way to go. But what do you find complicated about  `GUI.Check = this`?

Comment: I went for the proposal of JesseC.Slicer. @botond.botos I don't find it complicated, I just wondered if there was a simpler way to do this.

Comment: Sorry, sometimes my thinking becomes binary: if somebody is looking for a simpler solution I suppose the previous one was complicated :)

Answer (score 0):

Here seems both the classes require reference of other class. Something similar to keeping reference of children and parent in winforms and WPF.

Here this means its an object more precisely the current. This seems a general practice to hold references each other.

Another mechanism instead of assigning is to inject via constructor.